# how to build a loess model in in R using time series data

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

dput(head(y1,20))

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1373256120, 1373256360, 1373256660, 
1373256960, 1373257260, 1373257560, 1373257860, 1373258220, 1373258460, 
1373258760, 1373259060, 1373259360, 1373259660, 1373259960, 1373260260, 
1373260620, 1373260860, 1373261160, 1373261460, 1373261760), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), cpu = c(2.5803, 2.7954, 
3.0855, 2.6414, 2.4603, 2.2053, 3.2352, 2.2437, 2.0264, 1.9006, 
4.331, 2.068, 1.999, 1.8115, 1.8955, 1.7475, 1.8565, 2.1557, 
1.9113, 1.3635)), .Names = c("time", "cpu"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to build a loess model as folows:

```
ls<-loess(cpu~time, data=y1)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
In addition: Warning message:
In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `loess` can be a bit fragile IME. Try playing around with the span; you can also use `family="gaussian"` to do least-squares fitting rather than the more complicated robustified method which is the default.

Comment: You could also use either `mgcv::gam` or `gam::gam`, which are other ways of fitting local regression models (albeit with splines in the former case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should convert your variables to numeric and ensure that they are finite.

```
with(y1,{
  ok <- is.finite(time) & is.finite(cpu)
  x <- as.numeric(time)[ok]   ## you reproduce  the error without coercion 
  y <- as.numeric(cpu)[ok]
  data <- list(x = x, y = y)
  loess( y~x,data = data)
})

loess(formula = y ~ x, data = data)
Number of Observations: 20 
Equivalent Number of Parameters: 4.42 
Residual Standard Error: 0.6174
```

Using `panel.smoother` from `latticeExtra` you can get the result without any manipulation(it should do the the job above internally)

```
library(latticeExtra)
xyplot(cpu ~ time ,type='l',data=y1)+
  layer(panel.smoother(y ~ x, span = 0.75),style=2)
```

[image]

Comment: @agsstudy, the purpose of this exercise is to extract out the modeled data and graph it in javascript. I see that within with loess works, but when I do it outside of the with, it does not work. how would I do something like this ls<-loess(cpu~time, data=y1)?

Comment: I use the `with` to avoid $ when I access the variables,...You can remove it like this :  ok <- is.finite(y1$time) & is.finite(y1$cpu)..and continue for all other statements...Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot() it's quite easy to plot loess models. It's the default for geom_smooth(). So you don't even need to calculate it, you can plot it directly.

```
df <- data.frame(time = as.numeric(dput$time), cpu = as.numeric(dput$cpu))

ggplot(df, aes(time, cpu)) + 
   geom_line(aes(colour = "red")) + geom_smooth(aes(colour = "black"))
```

Comment: Bel, yes, I love ggplot but only thing is that I need to make these charts interactive.